# Spring boot test throws - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/web/servlet/DispatcherServletCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I hope this will not be seen as a duplicate as I have tried other link but all proved futile.

I am trying to run Spring MVC test. After setting up the test class the error in the subject seems to be the only hinderance to have the test run successfully.

I have my test class setup as below. I have also tried using `@WebMvcTest`

```java
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EmployeesControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @MockBean
    private EmployeesService employeesService;;

    @MockBean
    private AuthService authService;
    @MockBean
    private  EmployeesValidation employeesValidation;

    @Test
    public void getEmployeesForLoggedUser() throws Exception {
        int resourceId = 100;
        EmployeesResponse employeesResponse = new EmployeesResponse(
                1,
                "Test",
                "test@gmail.com",
                "ENH",
                "",
                "",
                "Senior Software Engineer",
                null,
                null,
                FlexStatusType.WAITING_TO_APPROVE.name(), null,
                SkillStatusType.WAITING_TO_APPROVE.name(), null,
                TechMatrixStatusType.WAITING_TO_APPROVE.name(), ""
        );
        List<EmployeesResponse> employeesResponses = Collections.singletonList(employeesResponse);
        when(authService.getLoggedUserIdFromSession()).thenReturn(resourceId);
        when(employeesValidation.hasAccessViewMyEmployees(resourceId)).thenReturn(true);
        when(employeesService.getEmployees()).thenReturn(employeesResponses);
        this.mvc.perform(get("/api/employees")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is(employeesResponse.getName())));
    }


}
```

##### Pom file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mobica.myprofile</groupId>
    <artifactId>myprofile</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.18.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <!--S P R I N G -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- GOOGLE DOCS-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev614-1.18.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--T E S T S-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional dependencies for using Spock -->
        <dependency>
            <!-- use a specific Groovy version rather than the one specified by spock-core -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- enables mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces) -->
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- enables mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB) -->
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- only required if Hamcrest matchers are used -->
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!--D A T A B A S E -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>42.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--A P A C H E C O M M O N S -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--O T H E R -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--J A V A S L A N G-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.javaslang</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaslang</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <project.packaging>jar</project.packaging>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <properties>
                <project.packaging>war</project.packaging>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugins for using Spock -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>rnd-registry.mobica.com/bss/myprofile-backend-new</imageName>
                    <imageTags>
                        <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                        <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
                    </imageTags>
                    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Please note it is Spring-boot 1.5.18.RELEASE

Comment: Which IDE? How are you invoking the test? Please post your pom file.

Comment: I am using Intellij and I also updated the question with my pom file.

Comment: How are you invoking the test? Which menu navigation? or mvnw test? I need the whole pom

Comment: I am invoking it through the run button or mvn test. And that is all in the pom file.

Comment: OMG hope for you an archeologist passes by: spring-boot 1.5.18 was released late 2018 when 2.0.0 was already available (early 2018) and 3.0.0 is now arround.